# Wildcard route in restify

Tags: regex, node.js, express, restify

coming from express I have routes like

```
server.get('/some/route/*', function(req, res) { 

    // accessing wildcard 
    console.log(req.params[0]);

});
```

How does a wildcard route like this look in restify?

In restify I also want to access the wildcard part of the uri via `req.params[0]`.

thx

Answer (score 3):

How does a wildcard route like this look in restify?

Answer:
restify takes regular expression slightly different from express.js.  '/some/route/*' in express would be '/some/route/.*' in restify

In restify I also want to access the wildcard part of the uri via req.params[0].

Answer:
restify doesn't put the wildcard part in req.params like express does, so the wildcard part needs to be parsed manually from req.url as below:

```
var path = req.route.path;
var wildcard = req.url.split(path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('.')))[1];
```

So with the above code, wildcard part of '/some/route/this/is/my/route' would be this/is/my/route

Answer (score 1):

This would be help:

```
var url = req.url,
    wildcardUrl = '';
wildcardUrl = url.split('/some/route/')[1];

//do something to wildcardUrl
```